# IF MariaDB phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger, mariadb

Estou tentando criar uma trigger usando o phpmyadmin com banco MariaDB
mas quando chega na linha if ele dá uma mensagem:

> unrecognized statement type. (near IF)

A trigger é essa:

```
SET @TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente C WHERE C.NR_CPF = NEW.NR_CPF);


IF @TOTAL > 0 THEN BEGIN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred'
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o correto, mantendo essa lógica, seria:

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE total BIGINT;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO  @total 
    FROM  cliente C
     WHERE C.NR_CPF = NEW.NR_CPF;

  IF @total > 0 THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'An error occurred'; 
  END IF;

END
```

Uma outra forma seria somente adicionar `BEGIN` e `END` e um `;` para corrigir, assim:

```
BEGIN

  SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente C WHERE C.NR_CPF = NEW.NR_CPF);

  IF @total > 0 THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  END IF;

END
```

Comment: quando chega na palavra IF dá a menssagem `unrecognized statement type. (near IF)`